# Is setAdapter() necessary after notifyDataSetChanged in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is `recyclerview.setAdapter(adapterObj)` always necessary after 
`adapterObj.notifydataSetChanged()` ?

Note:- The context at which I ask the question is that I have some instances where the recyclerview doesnot reload the data after I have updated the Data Structure, and called `adapterObj.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: if the only data changed then no need to call recyclerview.setAdapter(adapterObj) if the reference of data is changed then  need to call set adapter

Comment: noooo, it's not required, you should increase your knowledge on how notifydatasetchanged works

Comment: @Pavan It is necessary if I do ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>() right?

Comment: yes right, you need to call set adapter if you create ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>()

Comment: @SarthakMittal check with changing reference

Comment: If you guys think this is a good question, please upvote.

Comment: @Pavan we should avoid changing references, and even if we do it we don't need to call setadapter if we can refer the list used in adapter, to the new reference

Comment: that i know but my explanation is regarding when we need to call setadapter therefor i mentioned if reference changed then must need to call setadapter

Answer (score 1):

No, it should be needed to be set just once when setting everything up. `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is enough to reload the recycler view.

Comment: I have instances where the recyclerview doesnot refresh itself after calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: This should not be happening. post your code of the reyclerview, adapter and view holders.

Comment: Oops, I think the reference has changed. ie, I have done a DS DsObj = new DS();